# Apache POI excel ready read column from A to N

Tags: javascript, java, groovy, apache-poi, katalon-studio

I have written below codes by using Apache POI classes to read data from excel sheet. currently it reads row name + column name.

I would like to enhance it to allow me input many column name in case I have many Data columns.

I need help to get an idea how to enhance it.

currently, it only reads `("rowName", "columnName")`

the test data could grow horizontally at excel sheet from columnA.....columnN
I wanted something like this `("rowName", "columnNameA" till "columnNameN....")` .
is this possible? or any other better suggestion??

```html
public class readexcel {


 //method defined for reading a cell
 @Keyword
 private static  findData(String rowName, String columnName) throws IOException {
  String cellValue = ReadCellData(rowName, columnName);
  System.out.println(cellValue);
 }


 private static String ReadCellData(String rowName, String columnName) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/testmatrix.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
  int rowNameColIdx = findColumnIdx("Automation TC", firstRow);
  int colNameColIdx = findColumnIdx(columnName, firstRow);

  Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
  rowIterator.next();
  while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
   Row row = rowIterator.next();
   if (rowName.equals(row.getCell(rowNameColIdx).getStringCellValue())) {
    return row.getCell(colNameColIdx).getStringCellValue();
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

 private static int findColumnIdx(String text, Row row) {
  for (Cell cell : row) {
   if (text.equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
    return cell.getColumnIndex();
   }
  }
  return -1;
 }





}
```

Read data script

```
def exceldata = CustomKeywords.'test.readexcel.ReadCellData'("rowName", "columnName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your spreadshseet looks something like

```
| Test1 | Test 2 | Test C |
| A     | 1      | aa     |
| B     | 2      | bb     |
```

And you want to be able to say *give me the values for Test2 and Test C in row 2*, then I'd suggest you do it in two steps. Firstly, build a mapping from Column Names to column indexes. Secondly, read specific cells from a row.

Since you've tagged [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) I'd suggest code something like:

```
int headerRowNumber = 0 // 0-based row numbering
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0) // what sheet to read from

Map<String,Integer> colNamesToNumbers = [:]
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter()

sheet.getRow(headerRowNumber).each { cell ->
   // Render the column heading to a string, in case it's a number
   String heading = fmt.formatCellValue(cell)
   colNamesToNumbers[heading] = cell.getColumnIndex()
}
```

Then to do the reading, something like

```
Closure readValues = { int rowNum, List<String> columnNames ->
   Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum)
   if (row == null) return []

   return columnNames.collect { String name ->
      int colNum = colNamesToNumbers[name]
      return fmt.formatCellValue( row.getCell(colNum) )
   }
}

List<String> valsRow2 = readValues(2, ["Test1","Test C"])
// returns ["B","bb"]
List<String> valsRow7 = readValues(7, ["Test 2"])
// returns [] as no row 7
```

Comment: from your sample i wanted to read List<String> valsRow2 = readValues(A, ["Test 2","Test C"])
// returns ["1","aa"]
how to not using "valsRow2" because counting row is not easy, my scrip always uses name instead of counting row number or column number. so when i put "A" the program knows i wanted to read Row with name "A".

Comment: If you have a column of row names, just iterate over all of those storing another map of cell values to row numbers, then lookup the row number at fetch time from that